# Search and replace words in Java

Tags: java, string, search, replace

I have a string, with characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `(`, `)`, `+`, `-`, etc.

I want to find every word within that string and replace it with the same word with `'word'` (single quotes added). Words in that string can be preceded/followed by "(", ")", and spaces.

How do I go about doing that?

Input:

```
(Movie + 2000)
```

Output:

```
('Movie' + '2000')
```

Comment: Regular Expressions are especially suited for this kind of work; They will do it in linear time, and even in a single line of code.

Comment: Can you pls show some example input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, regex is a good way to go:

```
String input = "(Movie + 2000)";

input = input.replaceAll("[A-Za-z0-9]+", "'$0'");
```

You don't give a precise defition of 'word', so I assume it is any combination of letters and numbers.

**EDIT** OK, thanks to @Buhb for explaining why this solution is not the best one. Better solution was given by @Bohemian.

Comment: Waaay too complicated. Regex already HAS a definition for "word boundary" - it's \b: See my solution

Comment: @Bohemian: well, I keep forgetting about those. is that a reason for downvote?

Comment: The solutions are different as well. If you want quotes around words like crêpe, this solution won't work. That might be ok depending on your use case (I don't know if non-english characters are included in "etc." in the question).

Answer (score 7):

**Keep it simple!** This does what you need:

```
String input = "(Movie + 2000)";

input.replaceAll("\\b", "'");  
// Outputs  "('Movie' + '2000')"
```

This uses the regex `\b`, which is a "word boundary". What could be simpler?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String str1 = "Hello string";
    String str2 = "str";

    System.out.println(replace(str1, str2, "'" + str2 + "'"));
}

static String replace(String str, String pattern, String replace) {
    int s = 0;
    int e = 0;
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    while ((e = str.indexOf(pattern, s)) >= 0) {
        result.append(str.substring(s, e));
        result.append(replace);
        s = e + pattern.length();
    }
    result.append(str.substring(s));
    return result.toString();
}
}
```

Output:  Hello 'str'ing

WBR

Comment: I don't know what words I have to replace so i can't manually do it as you've done.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to return string only if a replacement took place, see below:

```
if(s>0)
    return result.toString();
else
    return null;
```

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer to this question. Very poor quality. Consider reading -> https://stackoverflow.com/help